# in Objective-C, value of type double/float can only be NAN, INFINITY, & normal number?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

I knew double or float value can be not only normal value(-1.3, 0, 1.0, 2.3) but also NAN and INFINITY in Objective-C.

Is there other special values except for NAN and INFINITY for double/float value in Objective-C?

Comment: There are no other "special" values that exists.  Besides this easily could be answered by looking at the specification for double/float within the current Objective-C documentation.

Comment: @Ramhound of course, I sometimes tried searching in XCode Organizer's Documentation and google. But I couldn't find. Could you tell me the link to the document if you know it?

Comment: Google for "IEEE 754". There is of course +0 and -0 which are equal but not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primitive types in Objective-C are covered by the C standard, since ObjC is an OOP system grafted to C.

Which transforms your question to "What special values are there for float/doubles in C?"

Most (if not all) compilers will generate float and double arithmetic that conforms to IEEE 754. In this standard, there are 2 types of NaNs (signalling and quiet), 2 infinities (+Infinity, -Infinity) and finite numbers (which include signed zeros, +0 and -0). The topic is too wide to even start, and you'd do yourself a favor by reading a book about floating point arithmetic.

**However** the C language standard (before C99) does not make any guarantees for conformance to IEEE 754 and this is only a de-facto standard.

Also, in C you check for NaN values with the `isnan` function.

Comment: @KSteff thanks for detailed answer. it was helpful.

Comment: Actually NANs can have a payload. Therefore there are two kinds of NANs (signaling and quiet) but each kind has multiple values. Not all implementations, however, have reasonable support for defining/accessing the payload or any guaranteed support for it.

Comment: @AnalogFile Indeed, it seems I missed to point that out. The main point I wanted to make was the topic is too wide to be answered here in a reasonable way.

Answer (score -4):

There's also `DBL_EPSILON`, `LDBL_EPSILON` and `FLT_EPSILON`; `FLT_MIN`, `FLT_MAX`, [etc](https://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-934.3/float.h).

Comment: These are constants which are floating point values, not different kinds of floating point value. You may as well add PI, e, and 42 to your list.

Comment: @PeteKirkham And how PI would help you with floating-point arithmetic? Yep, not kinds, but may be pretty useful to prevent mistakes with floating values anyway.

Comment: I would put this suggestion to comment, not answer, but ironically have no karma enough yet.